# BeautifulSoup returning unrelated HTML

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I'm trying to parse basketball stat data from pages like http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/boxscores/2014-11-14-kentucky.html. I'm using Python 2.7.6 and BeautifulSoup 4-4.3.2. I'm searching gamelogs like the above page for the class "sortable" in order to get access to the raw stat data contained within the tables. I am only interested in the "Basic Stats" for each team.

However, the HTML that BeautifulSoup is returning is not at all what I expect. Instead I get a list of all-time team records and data for every school that has ever played. I don't have enough reputation to post a second link here of the output or I would.

Basically, there are four class "sortable" tables on the boxscore page. When I ask BS to find them by the only way I can think of to distinguish them from the other data, it instead returns completely irrelevant data and I can't even figure out where the returned data comes from.

Here's the code:

```
import urllib2
import re
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Gamelogs():

    def __init__(self):

        #the base bage that has all boxscore links
        self.teamPageSoup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(
        'http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/' + school +
        '/2015-gamelogs.html'))
        #use regex to only find links with score data       
        self.statusPageLinks = self.teamPageSoup.findAll(href=re.compile(
        "boxscores"));

def scoredata(links, school):
    #for each link in the school's season   
    for l in links:
        gameSoup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(l))
        #remove extra link formatting to get just filename alone
        l = l[59+len(school):]
        #open a local file with that filename to store the results
        fo = open(str(l),"w")
        #create a list that will hold the box score data only   
        output = gameSoup.findAll(class_="sortable")
        #write it line by line to the file that was just opened 
        for o in output:
            fo.write(str(o) + '\n')
        fo.close

def getlinks(school):
    gamelogs = Gamelogs()
    #open a new file to store the output
    fo = open(school + '.txt',"w")
    #remove extraneous links
    gamelogs.statusPageLinks = gamelogs.statusPageLinks[2:]
    #create the list that will hold each school's seasonlong boxscores
    boxlinks = list()
    for s in gamelogs.statusPageLinks:
        #make the list element a string so it can be sliced
        string = str(s)
        #remove extra link formatting
        string = string[9:]
        string = string[:-16]
        #create the full list of games per school
        boxlinks.insert(0, 'http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/'
        + school + string)
    scoredata(boxlinks, school)     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #for each school as a commandline argument  
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        school = arg    
        getlinks(school)
```

Is this a problem with BS, my code, or the site? T

Comment: Most of us here would like to see a lot more debugging information - some prints during the process would go a long ways to answering your question(s).  Post an answer if you can't update the OP (or create a new post with all the relevant information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue with your code. The page that you are getting back sounds like this one: http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/?redir

Whenever I enter an invalid school name I am redirected to a page showing stats for 477 different teams. FYI: team names in the url are also case sensitive.

Comment: This was the issue, my formatting when inserting each link to `boxlinks` was incorrect, I misread the proper link. I just needed to remove `/cbb/schools/` and `school` from that statement. I was so focused on why I was getting such seemingly random data instead of debugging the root source it seems. Thank you.